# Examples of product of two $L^1_\text{loc}$ functions that is not $L^1_{\text{loc}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> Let $f\in L^1_\text{loc}$ and $g\in L^1_\text{loc}$, does $fg \in L^1_\text{loc}$?

My textbook says it isn't in a general case.
However if $g\in \mathcal{E} = \mathscr{C}^\infty$, then $fg\in L^1_\text{loc}$.

I can't seem to find a example of two locally integrable functions where the product is not locally integrable. I would need to find some function $g$ which is isn't $\mathscr{C}^\infty$ which would create a singularity? Could someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $$f(x) = g(x) = x^{-\alpha} \chi_{(0, 1)(x)}$$ for some $\alpha \in (1/2, 1)$ on $(0, 1)$.

Then $f$ and $g$ are not only locally integrable but also integrable, yet their product is not.

---

If this example is bothersome because of the singularity only being at one point, then a minor adjustment can be made so that there are many more: For example,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} 2^{-i} |x - q_i|^{-\alpha}$$

where $\{q_i\}$ is some enumeration of the rationals.

Comment: Why exclude $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @dietervdf No reason, I just don't like endpoints.

Comment: Intuitively, if a function $ f$  goes to infinity at a point then $1/f$ may be integrable if $f$ doesn't go to infinity "too fast", but $f^2$ goes "twice as fast",as in the answers given, e.g. $f(x)=1/\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 1):

What about $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=g(0)=0$ ?